# R how to group part of overlapped values among rows?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, reshape

I have a data frame that some rows that need to be further grouped by some of the overlapped values among rows

```
col1, col2
a1,   2;3 
a2,   2
a3,   3;4
a4,   4
a5,   2;4
a6,   5
a7,   5;6
a8,   6;7
```

The value **2** in col2 occurred in rows 1,2 and 5 can be grouped firstly since value **3** is with 2 in row 1 and value **4** with 2 in row 5 are defined as one group, then value 3 and 4 all can be counted as 1 group as 2;

Same for group 2 that value 5 is overlapped in rows 6 and 7, and value 6 and value 7 are the same case bonded, so they can be grouped into one group as well.

So, the output can be summarized into a new column called group like the following:

```
col1, col2, group
a1,   2;3,  1
a2,   2,    1
a3,   3;4,  1
a4,   4,    1
a5,   2;4,  1
a6,   5,    2    
a7,   5;6,  2
a8,   6;7,  2
```

Any idea to use tidyverse/dplyr to that? Great thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I did not understood the criteria to create the column group @Makunata

Comment: Can you explain about 'grouped by some of the overlapped values among rows'? if there is 2,2 in `col2`, then `group` should be 2?

Comment: The criteria are based on col2 that the first row and second row can be grouped as they all have overlapped value "2" and then they can also be grouped with a5 row. Since the fifth row has "4", then the 5th row can be grouped with a3 and a4 row. So lastly these 5 rows can be counted as 1 group.

Comment: The overlapped values referred to the col2 that 2 was overlapped in 3 rows, 1, 2, and 5 rows; 3 occurred in row 1 and 3; 4 in the row 3, 4, 5; Any thoughts?

Comment: do you mean that because every row is connected by some `n` degrees to every other row, via `col2` similarities, that all the rows belong to a group?  for example, if `a6` had a `col2` value of 9, this would be the only row in `group == 2`?  this sounds like a graph or set theory approach would be appropriate.

Comment: Hi Andrew_reece, yes, that is exactly what I mean. I will add group 2 in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a graph problem where you need to find connected subgraphs. This is pretty straigrforard with the `igraph` library, the only tricky part is reshapeing your data properly. So with the sample data

```
dd <- structure(list(col1 = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"), col2 = c("2;3", 
"2", "3;4", "4", "2;4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

You can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(igraph)

dd %>% 
  separate_rows(col2) %>% 
  select(col1, col2) %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>% 
  clusters() %>% 
  membership() %>% 
  tibble::enframe() %>% 
  right_join(dd, by=c("name"="col1"))
```

We expand the data into different rows then connect all the edges in an undirected graph. We run a simple community detection and coerce those results back into a data frame that we join back to the original data. This does make the assumption that the values in col1 don’t overlap with the values stored in col2.

Comment: Great thanks MrFlikc! You are my hero! For other newbies who will have the same problem, note that you'd put the col1 and col2 as the first 2 columns when you have a larger data frame while using graph_from_data_frame() function.